# emacs: navigating multifile latex docs with tags

Tags: emacs, latex, tags, ctags, bibtex

I find [Emacs tags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html) a very useful feature to navigate through source code that can be in different files. Since some of my documents in LaTeX are very long and with many `\include`'s, I thought it would be a nice thing to use the Emacs tags feature with LaTeX (sometimes I spend too much time trying to find a certain subsection, for instance). Reftex has a nice feature provided by the command `reftex-toc` with works with multifile documents, but I have the impression that it's easier to locate some unknown section with find-tag instead (unless if someone can convince me otherwise).

However, at least in my experience, the command `ctags -e` does not parse some of my .tex files correctly (e.g., some existing sections are not available), and things get worse with I try to use with multifile latex documents (i.e., with many `\include`'s). So I have the following questions: do you use the tags feature to navigate multifile LaTeX documents? Do you have similar problems and, if you do, do you use any hack? And the last question: what about bibtex files? Do you know of a way of using the tags feature with bibtex files?

And if you think that Emacs provides better ways to navigate through LaTeX muiltifile docs, please also share :-)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I use `reftex-toc`. It's great, especially for long documents such as a report or a thesis. But if I'm writing a shorter paper (or a strangely formatted paper), `reftex-toc` might not cut it, or it might be too slow (<kbd>C-c =</kbd> is a bit awkward to type on my keyboard), and in those rare situations, I use a hack called `ido-goto-symbol`, [which I found somewhere on emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode#toc10). Not good for multifile documents, tho.

In summary, I think `reftex-toc` is the way to go for large documents. If you are looking for headers that are hard to navigate to otherwise, it might be worth to restructure the document.

Comment: Thanks! I'm already having lots of fun playing with ido-goto-symbol. Just out of curiosity, have you tried the idomenu.el as well? (its link is just before the code for ido-goto-symbol you've posted)

Comment: No, I haven't tried `idomenu.el`, I find `ido-goto-symbol` more than enough for my needs. It's useful for most things I do, including bibtex-editing (ok, `ebib` is better for adding/handling, but for quick edits `ido-goto-symbol` is really handy).

Answer (score 0):

You can get an outline menu of all your sections by typing:

```
M-x imenu-add-menubar-index
```

Also, from the [AucTeX cheat sheet](http://devcheatsheet.com/static/pdf/auctex-ref.pdf), where the last 5 commands listed pertain to navigation:

> ### Outlining TEX Documents
>
> AUCTEX supports outline mode by defining section, subsection, etc. as heading levels. You can use
>
> ```
> M-x outline-minor-mode RET
> ```
>
> to toggle outline minor mode. All outline minor mode commands are under the prefix key specified by outline-minor- mode-prefix, default is “C-c @”.
>
> ```
> Hide all of buffer except headings       C-c @ C-t
> Show all text in buffer                  C-c @ C-a
> Hide body following this heading         C-c @ C-c
> Show body following this heading         C-c @ C-e
> Hide subtree                             C-c @ C-d
> Show subtree                             C-c @ C-s
> All subheadings visible                  C-c @ C-k
> next visible heading                     C-c @ C-n
> previous visible heading                 C-c @ C-p
> forward to next subheading               C-c @ C-f
> backward to next subheading              C-c @ C-b
> up one heading level                     C-c @ C-u
> ```

[AucTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) supports multiple files, too.